# What's wrong with my AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<script>

function newQuote() {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1",
      success: function(data) {
        //console.log('success', data);
        quote = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#content').html(quote[0].content);
        $('#author').html(quote[0].title);
      }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var quote; 
  newQuote();
  $('#getQuote').click(function(event) {
    newQuote();
  });
});

</script>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <h1>Random Quote Machine</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="well" id="content">
        The quote will go here
      </div>

      <div id="author">The author will go here </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
          <button id="getQuote" class="btn btn-primary">Get Quote </button>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to make a random quote machine using AJAX to request from an API, but when I click the button labeled *get quote* nothing happens. What's wrong with my AJAX request? Did I get the syntax wrong?

EDIT: I implemented the changes suggested but it still doesn't work. Here is the error message on my console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
>           at JSON.parse ()
>           at Object.success (VM333 pen.js:7)
>           at j (jquery.min.js:2)
>           at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>           at x (jquery.min.js:4)
>           at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Check the console. And make sure your `API`(url) is correct.

Comment: Your API is returning a JSON with array of values. try using `quote[0].content`

Comment: Why are you calling newQuote multiple times in HTML & Javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON+Node.js - Unexpected token o](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654733/jsonnode-js-unexpected-token-o)

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr:

Don't call [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in the success callback (since it expects a string as the first argument). The *data* argument is already a JSON object.

```
success: function(data) {
    quote = data;
    $('#content').html(quote[0].content);
    //..rest of success handler code 
}
```

#### Error message:

Looking in the browser console, one can see this error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

That is a clue that it is a trying to parse a (JSON) object as a string.

If you were to check [*typeof*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) data, it should tell you it is an *object*.

```
console.log('success - typeof data: ', typeof data);
```

#### The cause:

If you look at **Response headers** (see pasted below) of the request to get the quote, you will notice the **Content-Type** header is "*application/json; charset=UTF-8*". From The jQuery documentation for [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#data-types):

> If `json` is specified, the response is parsed using [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) before being passed, as an object, to the success handler. <sup>[1](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)</sup>

Header output:

> **Response Headers**:
>   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://run.plnkr.co
>   Content-Length:300
>   Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
>   ...

#### Fix:

Don't call [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in the success callback (since it expects a string as the first argument). The *data* argument is already a JSON object.

```
function newQuote() {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "//quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1",
      success: function(data) {
        quote = data;
        $('#content').html(quote[0].content);
        $('#author').html(quote[0].title);
      }
    });
}
```

See it demonstrated in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rZCHST9KMoiiquiHbX0O?p=preview).

---

<sup>1</sup> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Answer (score -1):

```
function newQuote() {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1",
      success: function(data) {
        //console.log('success', data);
        quote = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#content').html(quote[0].content); // selecting first child of array is the point
        $('#author').html(quote[0].title);
      }
    });
}
```

also remove the duplicate call to newQuote from onclick when you have attached it through Jquery.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should remove the onclick event attribute from the button html tag.